# How do mobile browsers differ vs desktop browsers for loading a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I am having some really weird things happen when I try to render a `position: fixed` left nav. For desktop it renders flawlessly, and the same is visible on a desktop page *with the same resolution* as a mobile:

[image: nav renders with the bottom: 0 properly applied]

However, when using firefox's (or chrome's) iPad / iPhone simulator, sometimes it looks like this:

[image: bottom of left nav extends the whole size of body]

You can clearly see that the bottom of the left nav follows the `bottom: 0` property applied to it, and with mobile browsers the `bottom: 0` goes beyond the end of viewport. On same pages it's far longer than other pages

This interestingly stops being an issue when I turn off **touch simulation** on firefox's dev tools.

Here is the CSS I use for it:

```
nav.left-nav {
    width: @navWidth;
    background: @navBackground--dark;
    font-size: @fontSizeBase;
    line-height: @lineHeightBase;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: @zIndex-2;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: @leftNavAnimation;

    .theme--light & {
        background: @navBackground--light;
    }

    &--closed {
        transform: translateX(-@navWidth);
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *bottom:0;* use...

```
height:calc(100% - 0px);
```

Comment: it does fix the height issue, but the anchoring no longer applies, it scrolls with the page

Comment: Replace position: fixed; with absolute,

Comment: then i don't have a fixed left nav anymore